# SQL query returns zero results in production, works locally

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am building a [news aggregator](https://news.zavoon.com/en) website using Laravel and I have a very bizarre issue where identical setup gives me different results. On the website I have one link/post which shows up in "new" links but not in "top" and "low" while locally it shows everywhere. I tried exporting the live database and importing it into my local development environment which replicated the issue locally. I've also tried resetting the live database but that didn't get the issue resolved.

I've narrowed down the issue to this SQL query, which for some reason doesn't return the one result which it should:

```
select links.id, links.title, links.url, links.user_id,  links.created_at, 
                  sum(vote) as votes,
                  (sum(vote)) / POWER(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(now(),links.created_at))/3600, 1.8) as rank
                  from links, votes
                  where links.language_id = 2 AND links.id = votes.link_id
                  group by links.id
                  order by rank, links.id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I am not sure where to take it from here.

Any help much appreciated : )

Comment: So you got the same issue locally after you imported the production database? And where is `top` and `low` you mentioned referenced? What do you do with the data after it's fetched? What is the expected result from this query and what is the actual result? There are too many unknowns here.

Comment: Tip of today: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax - easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: You'll need to post the database schema and the data that is not showing up (sanitized is fine) for help.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, it won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @RaymondNijland, does MySQL support _functionally dependent columns_ now? I wasn't aware of that! Thanks for the info!

Comment: @jarlh so I need to rewrite it with a join?

Comment: @PetarVasilev, you don't have to, old implicit joins still work. But explicit joins are good programming practice.

Comment: @jarlh i removed mine comment because MySQL 5.6 does not support it. My local server MySQL 5.7.20 seems to support it... but i don't think you should not rely on it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I'm so old so I'll probably keep following my _general GROUP BY rule_ forever. If you follow it, you'll never go wrong, no matter which dbms you use.

Comment: Well i would love to see the example tables and data on a sqlfiddle to see if we can repeat this problem.

Comment: I'll set it up @RaymondNijland

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a7a62/1 - this is with a dump of the live database

Comment: Well the sqlfiddle gives a error geuss that is more a warning on that query.. `Data truncation: DOUBLE value is out of range in 'pow((time_to_sec(timediff(now(),`db_9_5a7a62`.`links`.`created_at`)) / 3600),1.8)'`

Comment: Furthermore, I also get DOUBLE value... error on live database when running from phpmyadmin; however locally it returns one result...

Comment: I think it's not smart to also include the users table.. well atleast you are using bcrypt those hashes can't be bruteforced locally or cracked by a rainbow table

Comment: I'll try to rewrite with an inner join, hope that works. my sql skills are low.

Comment: @RaymondNijland none if the data is in actual use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159243/discussion-between-petar-vasilev-and-raymond-nijland).

Comment: @jarlh so if I don't have to rewrite with a JOIN what do I need to do to fix the issue? thanks